# Add a CSS Class inside <ngx-datatable-column

Tags: angularjs

I need to add a CSS class directly inside the header `<ngx-datatable-column ...>`.  First, I use a normal class

```
<ngx-datatable-column class="myClass"...>
```

myClass doesn't show up.  Then I try

```
<ngx-datatable-column [headerClass]="myClass"...>
```

It doesn't show, either!

Please help me how to add a CSS class directly inside a header of `<ngx-datatable-column ...>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure about it, but try this instead :

```
<ngx-datatable-column headerClass="myClass"...>
```

Answer (score 2):

not enough quotes

```
<ngx-datatable-column [headerClass]="'myClass'"...>
```